# PHP Array to string conversion error

Tags: php, search, indexing

```
148         /**
149          * Count
150          *
151          * Count relevant search results for a specific term
152          *
153          * @param       string  $query  Query or terms to search for
154          * @return      array
155          */
156         public function count($query)
157         {
158                 return $this->db
159                         ->where('MATCH(title, description, keywords) AGAINST ("*'.$this->db->escape_str($query).'*" IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0', null, false)
160                         ->count_all_results('search_index');
161         }
```

Line 159 outputs Array to string conversion error. It's driving me crazy. :(

Comment: Well, `$query` probably is an array? It's hard to tell without more data. Can you give some more specific info?

Comment: You could var_dump() with $query to find out what type it is and maybe even where it's coming form.

Comment: probably want to an implode or something to $query

Comment: it's an array containing the searched strings, something like this:

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "string1" [1]=> string(7) "string2" }

Comment: @Alexander You are passing the array into the function, and the query is trying to execute the entire array as a string, which it can't do.

Comment: so i should do a foreach and sum them?

Comment: would something like this be okay? http://pastebin.com/HTMGqBf2

Comment: with $q instead of $query in the long line

Answer (score 0):

change

return $this->db
                        ->where('MATCH(title, description, keywords) AGAINST ("*'.$this->db->escape_str($query).'*" IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0', null, false)
                        ->count_all_results('search_index');

TO

return implode($this->db
                        ->where('MATCH(title, description, keywords) AGAINST ("*'.$this->db->escape_str($query).'*" IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0', null, false)
                        ->count_all_results('search_index'));

Comment: Please use code formatting to make the answer clearer.